# Sybase and PowerApps

Tags: powerapps

I currently am trying to build a PowerApps that needs to connect to Sybase database. I do not see any connector for Sybase in PowerApps.

I'd like to ask for options on how I can connect to Sybase? I saw one option which is CData Connect Cloud which comes at a price. Aside from this, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Azure Functions app that connects to your Sybase database. Azure functions can be integrated with Power Platform via Custom connectors. You can create your actions like Post, Put, Get et cetera then.

This is an easy workaround in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment on things yet but anyway does Sybase have an api that you can use normal post/get/patch functions to get access to if so make a custom connector there are plenty of places on the internet that show how to do that such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b4aJdQrmTsQ or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6wqTV4wtPd8 and I'm pretty sure https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC7_OGRP8BYvtGB8eZdPG6Ng has some vids on it as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you only need read-only access to the data. You could create a Dataflow to Synchronise the data from Sybase to Dataverse (using the Sybase connector that is available in PowerQuery).

Then connect the app to Dataverse.

Won't help you if you need to update the data though.